# Extract data from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse some data from wunderground JSON, without using foreach cycle, only for the first day. Example from this JSON: http://api.wunderground.com/api/f429b85619ed45e8/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json

I want to get only the first day:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://api.wunderground.com/api/f429b85619ed45e8/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$weekday = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday[0]'}->{'date'}->weekday;
```

I've googled a lot and tried lot's of examples, but usually i get error or nothing.
help?

Comment: `$parsed_json->forecast->simpleforecast->forecastday[0]->date->weekday`?

Comment: Aah ok got it work. What's the difference?

Comment: `forecastday` is an array.  When you were putting `{'forecastday[0]'}`, that's as if the name was `forecastday[0]`.  The name is actually `forecastday`, and the array index is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. It is just that you needed to evaluate the array element after getting the object in the forecastday

```
    <?php
    $json_string = file_get_contents('http://api.wunderground.com/api/f429b85619ed45e8/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json');
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
    echo $weekday = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'simpleforecast'}->{'forecastday'}[0]->{'date'}->weekday;
    ?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7ws-pry

Answer (score 0):

You access the methods on the objects wrong:

Since I am not sure what property you want to get, here is how you determine what is in the variable:

```
 var_dump($parsed_json->forecast);
```

(And there is no "simpleforcast" there).